# Resolving relative imports within python namespace packages

Tags: python-3.x, package

My python directory structure is as follows

```
├── a
│   └── b
│       └── c
│           └── d
│               ├── bar.py
│               └── foo.py

└── sandbox.py
```

Directory `a/*` is auto generated code, and so assume I dont have control over its structure.

bar.py

```
def toto():
    pass
```

foo.py (intentionally not importing from a)

```
from b.c.d.bar import toto

def baz():
    pass
```

sandbox.py

```
from a.b.c.d.foo import baz


if __name__ == '__main__':
    baz()
```

The code executes with `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'b'`. Is there is a way around this error without making any changes to `a/*`? I recall being able to achieve this before using pythons `setuptools` and installing `a`, but unfortunately have not been able to reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a real answer to the question since it goes against the constraints of my problem, so I wont post it as the accepted answer.

A resolution if you are able to add a single file.

Inside of `a/__init__.py` I added:

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```